# getting the right text from a button in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

```
 public class tCalculator implements ActionListener{
   //private JTextField resultText;
    public void Calculator(){
        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
          btn3.addActionListener(this);
          }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object sourc = evt.getSource();          
        String source = evt.getActionCommand();
         System.out.println(source);
        jTextArea1.append(source);        
    }}
```

hello

this is a part of my program through which i am trying to make a calculator by using buttons in netbeans. what i am trying to do is to get the text within the button and print it in a jtextfield but when i press the button. on running the program the text is not coming in the right number. if i press "1" it doesn't display the first time. in the second time it comes once and then maybe int he third time it comes four times but the display is random and it is not known how many time it would display.help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the NetBeans GUI editor is getting in your way. You might start with an [sscce](http://sscce.org/); the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) has several such examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton){
            JButton but = (JButton) source;
            String text = but.getText();  //do what you want with the text
        }
}}
```

Comment: what does the jbutton represent?

Comment: I assumed that btn1 is a JButton. You didn't post the declaration of btn1. what is btn1?

Comment: but the problem is that there are multiple buttons so which one should i implement. also if i only write JButton it is giving me an error saying that it connot find the symbol.

Comment: i have declared all the buttons as Jbuttons but then when i copied the code given by you the the netbeans is showing an error saying that it can't find symbol JButton.

Comment: you have to import JButton: import javax.swing.JButton;

Comment: that has been done automatically when i made a new JButton in the design area and it is there in the code but then also it is showing the same error when i am writing it.

Comment: this is my last comment..if you want more help post some more code.

Comment: @siddhant: you would do well to study the tutorials to gain an understanding of what you are doing.